# unable to convert a class model properties to list in.net

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my code of class

```
public class WMBillable
    {
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int MonthNum { get; set; }
    }
```

this is my method which contains:

```
 foreach (var dt in lDistinctDate)
                {

                    WMNB = new WMBillable();

                    DateTime Cur = new DateTime();

                    Cur = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.InvoiceDate);

                    WMNB.MonthNum = Convert.ToInt32(Cur.Month);

                    WMNB.Year = Convert.ToInt32(Cur.Year);

                    lstWMB.Add(WMNB);
                }



                var CurrentMonthYear = lstWMB.OrderByDescending(item => item.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Month).FirstOrDefault();

                List<WMBillable> lstQu = CurrentMonthYear.ToList();
```

in this line of code   `List<WMBillable> lstQu = CurrentMonthYear.ToList()`, I am unable to convert the extracted linq query to a list. I got the error like "WMBillable does not contain a definition for ToList() and no extension method toList accepting a first argument of type WMBillable could be found".

If I go for auto correction it is generating internal list inside my model class like this

```
public class WMBillable
    {
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int MonthNum { get; set; }

        internal List<WMBillable> ToList()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I have no idea to correct this..Kindly help this dot net beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling FirstOrDefault:

```
var CurrentMonthYear = lstWMB.OrderByDescending(item => item.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Month).FirstOrDefault();
```

By this you either get the FIRST or DEFAULT value, which is just ONE.
Try:

```
var CurrentMonthYear = lstWMB.OrderByDescending(item => item.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Month);
```

which will return an IEnumerable collection which can be converted to list.

[MSDN FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var CurrentMonthYear = lstWMB.OrderByDescending(item => item.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Month);

List<WMBillable> lstQu = CurrentMonthYear.ToList();
```

Remove `FirstOrDefault` function call, then you will be able to convert.

Comment: Yes..Thank you @Akshey Bhat